# Inserting action properties into custom story attachment

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom) doesn't describe how to insert action properties into an attachment, using this dialog:

[image: Custom story attachment dialog]

For example, if I share a story with these properties:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'appnamespace:Adore',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify(
        {
           person: 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/1920325/eye-mew',
           reason: 'He has a flawless jawline'
        })
    },
    function(response){}
});
```

How would I expose the `reason` property of the `Adore` action, in the attachment caption?

Comment: Start typing a `{` curly brace into those fields, then suggestions for properties you can use will show up.

Comment: Thanks! @CBroe Want to turn this into an answer which I'll accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I expose the `reason` property of the `Adore` action, in the attachment caption?

Start typing a `{` curly brace into those fields, then suggestions for properties you can use will show up.

(You’re right, this doesn’t seem to be mentioned in the docs any more.)

Comment: yes this works. But it is not possible to bring the captions into new lines.